# Robbiehanson xmpp framework for iOS not receiving chat messages

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

Trying to create a very simple proof of concept iOS xmpp app with the robbiehanson xmpp [frame work](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework), just need to be able to send and receive messages and roster data. I can authenticate and send messages successfully, but when users attempt to respond to my messages I do not receive them. I have implemented the didReceiveMessage delegate method as follows:

```
-(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message {
    NSLog(@"incoming message: %@", message);
}
```

but I never receive this log. If I log in with the existing web app or android app that communicates with this xmpp server I receive these messages, so I'm inclined to believe they are formatted properly. Is there a module I need to add to the XMPPStream for receiving messages? I'm setting up the stream like this (some of the string values have been changed for security and what not):

```
stream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
stream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
stream.hostName = @"hostname.com";
stream.hostPort = 5222;

XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage* xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc]      initWithInMemoryStore];
XMPPRoster* xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
[stream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

XMPPJID* jid = [XMPPJID jidWithUser:@"username" domain:@"domain.com" resource:@"iOS"];

[stream setMyJID:jid];

[xmppRoster activate:stream];

[stream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error]
```

and then in the xmppStreamDidConnect method I do this to authenticate

```
NSString *myPassword = @"password";
NSError *error = nil;

[stream authenticateWithPassword:myPassword error:&error]
```

When I am sending a message out I use this snippet:

```
 MPPJID* recipient = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"user@domain.com"];
XMPPMessage* message = [[XMPPMessage alloc] initWithType:@"chat" to:recipient];
[message addBody:@"hello world"];

[stream sendElement: message];
```

I'm thinking there is something simple I am missing that someone who has used this before will be able to point out to me right away.  I'm ready to supply other info if necessary for solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply needed to broadcast my presence, then I was able to receive messages.

I added these lines to the streamDidAuthenticate method

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
[sender sendElement:presence];
```